# How to merge rows when data when some columns are the same using Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

Now I have a dataframe. I want to separate the different values with commons and remove any nulls.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s1 = pd.Series(['a', np.nan,'i'])
s2 = pd.Series(['a','f',np.nan])
s3 = pd.Series(['a', 'e','i'])
s4 = pd.Series(['c', 'g','j'])
    
df = pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2), list(s3),list(s4)],  columns =  ['A', 'B','C'])
df


    A   B   C
0   a   d   NaN
1   a   f   NaN
2   a   e   i
3   c   g   j
```

Desired outcome:

```
    A   B       C
0   a   d,e,f   i
1   c   g       j
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
out = df.groupby('A',as_index=False).agg({'B':','.join,'C':'first'})
   A      B  C
0  a  d,f,e  i
1  c      g  j
```

Update

```
out = df.groupby('A',as_index=False).agg({'B':lambda x : ','.join(x.dropna().drop_duplicates()),'C':lambda x : ','.join(x.dropna().drop_duplicates())})
out
   A      B  C
0  a  d,f,e  i
1  c      g  j
```

Comment: Thanks! I test it. If the cell B0 in the original dataframe is NaN, the code seems not working.

Comment: if C0 is also 'i' instead of NaN. The result will be 'i,i', not merging.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the updated version. It is not metering, when if C0 is also 'i' instead of NaN.

Comment: That's right I got the same results, Now the cell in C0 is in the result is 'i,i', but the desired output is just 'i'

Comment: I just changed my original dataframe in the question. The desired outcome still the same. I am sorry for the confusion. Really appreciated your help!

Comment: Yes, works perfectly now! Thanks so much!